# Laptop battery starts producing a crackling sound when I plug the cable into the Laptop

Tags: laptop, battery

When I plug my laptop battery from HP into my laptop, it starts making this crackling noise. The battery has died on me once before in school (but I think it was just a defective outlet). I also remember hearing this crackling noise once before but don't know if it was on this new battery that I got about a few months ago (3-4) or if it was on the old one. I'm just really worried that something's going to happen again since I can't get another free battery through insurance since this has happened once before and I don't wanna pay for a new battery. If anyone could tell me if this "crackling" noise is dangerous or just a normal sound then I'd be very happy. By the way, it does not look like any physical damage occurred on the outside of the cable and battery.

Comment: How do you know it's the battery?

Comment: It could be an intermittent electrical connection inside the laptop.

Comment: After watching a program on the hazards of lithium-ion batteries, I would be concerned. Confirm that the noise is from the battery rather than the laptop: operate the laptop with just the AC adapter and without the battery, and then check for the "*crackling noise*".